# Argument x passed to phpbb_generate_debug_output() must be an instance of phpbb\user

Tags: php, symfony, phpbb

I am using phpBB to create a simple Community. So, I want to create a costum site, where I want to display certain groups with it's members.

The code is my very first try to create a costum site.

I have the members.php

```
<?php
    define('IN_PHPBB', true);
    $phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
    $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

    // Start session management
    $user->session_begin();
    $auth->acl($user->data);
    $user->setup();

    // Inits Languagefile
    page_header('test');

    // Groups that should displayed
    $group_ids = array(
        5,
        9,
    );

    // Get Groups from Database
    $sql = 'SELECT group_id, group_name, group_desc FROM ' . GROUPS_TABLE . ' WHERE ' . $db->sql_in_set('group_id', $group_ids);
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

    // Write Data for each Group
    while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {
        $template->assign_block_vars('unit', array(
            'GROUPNAME'     => $row['group_name'],
            'DESCRIPTION'   => $row['group_desc'],
        ));

        // Get Groupmembers from Database
        $sqlusers = 'SELECT user_id FROM ' . USER_GROUP_TABLE . ' WHERE group_id = ' . $row['group_id'];
        $users = $db->sql_query($sqlusers);

        // Get User from Database
        while ($user = $db->sql_fetchrow($users)) {

            $sql_arr = array(
                'SELECT'    => 'u.user_id, u.username, u.user_avatar, r.rank_title, r.rank_image',
                'FROM'      => array(
                    USERS_TABLE => 'u',
                    RANKS_TABLE => 'r'
                ),
                'WHERE'     => 'u.user_id = ' . $user['user_id'] . ' AND u.user_rank = r.rank_id',
            );
            $sqluserdata = $db->sql_build_query('SELECT', $sql_arr);

            $userdata = $db->sql_query($sqluserdata);         

            // Write Data for each User
            while($single = $db->sql_fetchrow($userdata)) {
                $template->assign_block_vars('unit.member', array(
                    'USERID'    => $single['user_id'],
                    'USERNAME'  => $single['username'],
                    'AVATAR'    => $single['user_avatar'],
                    'RANK'      => $single['rank_title'],
                    'RANGIMAGE' => $single['rank_image'],
                ));
            }
            $db->sql_freeresult($userdata);
        } 
        $db->sql_freeresult($users);
    }
    $db->sql_freeresult($result);

    // Load Template
    $template->set_filenames(array(
        'body' => 'members.html',
    ));

    // End Controller
    make_jumpbox(append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}viewforum.$phpEx"));
    page_footer();
?>
```

And of cause the styles/*/members.html:

```
<!-- INCLUDE overall_header.html -->

<div id="sub-header">
    <div class="chunk">
        <div class="sub-header-title">
            <h2 class="titlespace">Mitglieder</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="background-main">
    <div class="chunk">    
        <!-- BEGIN unit -->
        <div class="unit">
            <h3>{unit.GROUPNAME}</h3>
            <p>{unit.DESCR}</p>

            <!-- BEGIN unit.member -->
            <div class="unitmember" style="background-color:red;">
                <p>{unit.member.USERNAME}</p>
                <p>{unit.member.AVATAR}</p>
                <p>{unit.member.USERID}</p>
                <p>{unit.member.RANK}</p>
                <p>{unit.member.RANKIMAGE}</p>
            </div>
            <!-- END unit.member -->

        </div>
        <!-- END unit -->
    </div>
</div>


<!-- INCLUDE jumpbox.html -->
<!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html -->
```

I tested the data-output via var_dump, every was fine... but everytime I parse the template, It throws me this error:

"Catchable fatal error: Argument 4 passed to phpbb_generate_debug_output() must be an instance of phpbb\user, boolean given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\jgzga\includes\functions.php on line 5431 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\jgzga\includes\functions.php on line 5343"

I never touched the core-files of phpbb... so... maybe some of you can help me. ;)

Comment: Okay... It throws the error only with my query. When I comment the query out, It renders the - empty - page.

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as 3.1 version of phpBB forums has been released, you shouldn't place any custom code outside of **ext/** directory. All your modifications should be written as extensions with controllers, services, DI and so on. More info here: https://www.phpbb.com/extensions/writing/
2. In your case this error caused by your **$user** variable which is global in phpBB and has a special meaning — it represents an object for current user. You're overwriting it in a loop. On last iteration it becomes boolean false and then it is passed to phpbb_generate_debug_output() function. Rename this variable or (better) rewrite your code as an extension.